# Are there ATM fees in the Azores?

Tags: fees-and-charges, portugal, atms, azores

[ATM owners don't charge fees to withdraw cash in Portugal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATM_usage_fees#Portugal), regardless of your home bank or card issuer. (Of course any fees charged by your home bank / card issuer, e.g. for foreign transactions, are separate and still apply.)

Does this include ATMs on the Azores? Do the owners of ATMs on the Azores charge visitors fees to withdraw cash?

My card was issued in the USA, are there special fees for non-Portuguese/European cards?

Comment: What country is your card issuer from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azores are Portugal. I do not see any reason why it would be different than in continental Portugal. 
Anyway: if you will have to pay a fee, the fee amount will be displayd on the ATM screen (there is a EU directive about it) and you can always take your card and go to another ATM which will not want your money.

Looking into my bank papers - being on São Miguel in 2014 I didn't have to pay a withdrawal fee.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I was thinking the cost of doing business might be more so prices for some things might be higher in the Azores / there might be different rules than on the mainland.

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud I didn't pay extremely close attention when I was in the Azores, but I definitely got the distinct impression that prices were lower than in Lisbon.

Comment: @pnuts you've never been to Hawaii, I see.

Comment: At least one bank in Spain gets around the "E.U. directive" by getting you to approve a very small fee, and then charging a previously undisclosed "commission" that was NOT small.